# How to change icons on GNOME favorites bar?

Tags: 12.04, themes, icons

I'm new to Ubuntu, and I switched to GNOME and managed to change the icons! But when I open a program that has its own (new) icon on the favorites bar (if that's its name) I still see the original icon!

This also happens when I switch windows with Alt+Tab!

Is there a way I can change that?

EDIT:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: maybe you are talking about **dock**?

Comment: Any screenshots you could post would help.

Comment: @MatNadrofsky I wanted to do that but I couldn't take a screenshot when I hover over 'activities' or when I alt+tab. Can you tell me how to take screenshots? Because prtscr and pasting it doesn't work.

Comment: You can open the screenshot dialogue, and get it to take a screenshot after 4 or so seconds, during which you can open Activities to take a screenshot.

Comment: @Wilf I uploaded a screenshot!

Comment: Which program is the one without the icon changing, and which theme?

Comment: @Wilf It is Numix Circle icon theme and the program is Cisco Packet Tracer. The problem is that it has the icon hardcoded on a path instead of just a name so I changed that and then the program appears in search with the right icon but it doesn't work everywhere (you can see that on the screenshot)

Answer (score 0):

For changing icon settings etc, [`gnome-tweak-tool`](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gnome-tweak-tool) is rather effective.
[image]

You can also use it for managing [Gnome Shell Extensions](https://extensions.gnome.org/) and other things as well

Comment: This is the program I used to change the icons but they are still not on my favorites bar. I'll upload screenshot now!

Comment: silly question, but did you log in and out after you changed the icons?

Comment: @Jacob - Come to think of it, you can also reset by pressing 'Alt' + 'F2', entering 'r', and hitting 'Enter'...

Comment: @Jacob I did do it and I also turned off my PC after that because I did it few days ago!